# diminuição de código

Tags: android, android-studio

Tem algum outro jeito em realizar esse código?

Esse código está muito repetitivo, queria saber se é possível diminuir e deixar mais fácil o entendimento.

```
if (games.getBallId() == btnBal0l.getId()){
    btnBal0l.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}else if (games.getBallId() == btnBal02.getId()){
    btnBal02.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}else if (games.getBallId() == btnBal03.getId()){
    btnBal03.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}else if (games.getBallId() == btnBal04.getId()){
    btnBal04.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}else if (games.getBallId() == btnBal05.getId()){
    btnBal05.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}else if (games.getBallId() == btnBal06.getId()){
    btnBal06.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}else if (games.getBallId() == btnBal07.getId()){
    btnBal07.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
}
```

Comment: Dá pra melhorar com `switch { case:  }`, mas ficaria maior

Answer (score 4):

> Esta é uma resposta baseada em opiniões! Existem várias formas de realizar a mesma operação. Aqui apresento apenas uma, baseada no meu ponto de vista!

Acredito que existe uma forma de deixar mais legível.

Para isso, podemos quebrar as funcionaidades:

1. Selecionar um `Button` através de um `Id`
2. Setar o `background` em um `Button`

Sugiro que adicone os 7 botões em uma lista, logo após criá los!

**Exemplo**:

```
private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>(0);
buttons.add(btnBal0l);
```

Ao invés de manter uma referência na classe, e outro na lista, pode se criar diretamente na lista :

```
buttons.add(Button.class.cast(findViewById(R.id.btnBal01));
```

Para podermos pegar o Button através do `Id` da lista, vamos criar um método:

```
private Button getButtonById(int id){
    for(final Button b : buttons){
       if(id == b.getId()){
           return b;
     }
   }
  return null;
}
```

Agora vamos setar o `resource` no `Button`:

```
 private void setImageInButton(int gameId){
        final Button b = getButtonById(gameId);
        if( b != null){
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
        }
    }
```

Agora você pode chamar a funcção da seguinte forma:

```
setImageInButton( games.getBallId() );
```

**Segue o código completo e comentado:**

```
 /**
     * Vamos armazenar em uma lista, todos os botões...
     */
    private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>(0);


    /**
     * verifica se o Button com o mesmo id está na lista
     * O retorna, caso exista, senão retorna null.
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    private Button getButtonById(int id){
        for(final Button b : buttons){
            if(id == b.getId()){
                return b;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * Através de um id, seleciona o Button e adiciona a imagem caso não seja nulo!
     * @param gameId
     */
    private void setImageInButton(int gameId){
        final Button b = getButtonById(gameId);
        if( b != null){
            b.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ic_gps_action);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Se todos esses botões estiverem dentro de um mesmo layout, pode usar o método [findViewById()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)) da classe view(esse layout).

```
int id = games.getBallId();
Button button = (Button)layout.findViewById(id);
button.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.ball_verde);
```

Comment: Muito bom! +1...